# automatically edit repo webhook upon creation

Tags: github, events, repository, teamcity, webhooks

Does github generate an event when a Webhook is created within a repo?

Background:
We use an Enterprise version of TeamCity that sits behind a firewall and connects to github.com. TeamCity has a feature called 'Install GitHub Webhook', to which, when providing a repo url adds a webhook to the repo. The webhook is used by github on push to trigger a build in TeamCity.

As TeamCity sits behind a firewall, github.com has to reach it through a proxy. So the webhook url in github that looks like https://teamcity.build.internal.com/app/hooks/github/2efd332-adf2-dd3 cannot get to it. This needs to go through the proxy and so the url should look like https://proxy.internal.com/app/hooks/github/2efd332-adf2-dd3

Is it possible to automatically update the webhook url from something like:
https://teamcity.build.internal.com/app/hooks/github/2efd332-adf2-dd3
to
https://proxy.internal.com/app/hooks/github/2efd332-adf2-dd3

What I've tried:
I can update webhook using repo webhook config api https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/webhooks/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28. This api can be called from github app

To use this I need to identify when a webhook is created, so are there any events triggered on webhook creation?